# How to configure StoreFileListener to implement data retention with Chronicle Queue

Tags: chronicle, chronicle-queue

From the [website](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Queue#user-guide) , it mentions `You can add a StoreFileListener to notify you when a file is added, or no longer used. This can be used to delete files after a period of time.` But I don't see any manual regarding how to utilize `StoreFileListener` or any sample code to implement the data deletion after certain amount of time.

Could you help to provide some guidance? thanks

Sample code with `StoreFileListener` to delete the data file after certain amount of time

Answer (score 0):

The `StoreFileListener` is useful to remove old files almost immediately.
If you want to remove them after a few days, I suggest using a cron or system job to find and remove these.
Some clients remove them weekly on Sunday morning.